# cURL request responds differently on local and aws server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, curl

I ran the following curl request on my local as well as on production :-

`curl -o '/tmp/abc.jpg' -L  'http://static2.jassets.com/p/Justanned-Black-Solid-Winter-Jacket-4701-2573471-1-pdp_slider_l.jpg'`

While on my local the response was an image (which should be), on production it gave me the following response :-

`<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
An error occurred while processing your request.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;97&#46;42db387d&#46;1467706208&#46;103dbe0e
</BODY></HTML>`

Both my local and server run on ubuntu 14.04 and apache server.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tested from my own AWS server located in Ireland and it worked fine. Where is yours located?

Comment: My AWS server is located in Singapore. Does it have to do anything with server settings?

Comment: Apparently there are no good answers in SO which can accurately pin-point the problem, even though some of the posts were asked as early as 1-2 years back

Comment: @Shalin I don't know. It can be a lot of different things, have you tried it from another instance in the same region/zone to check that the problem isn't the production instance? Does wget work on the same file?

Comment: @bjelleklang I tried on another server in the same region. It works there. wget works for the same file.